# Module '__React' has no exported member 'PropTypes'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I install `Typings` by `typings`:

```
typings install --global --save dt~react
typings install --global --save dt~react-dom
```

But I got error like this:

```
src/components/Context.tsx(5,20): error TS2305: Module '__React' has no exported member 'PropTypes'.
src/components/Context.tsx(21,20): error TS2305: Module '__React' has no exported member 'PropTypes'.
```

Code is as follow:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    childContextTypes: {
        foo: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return { foo: "I m the grandparent" };
    }

    render() {
        return <Child />
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    context: any;

    static contextTypes: {
        foo: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Hello</div>;
    }
}
```